# the sequence of event loop in the javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am new to learn javascript; I encountered a big confusion when I was learning async await.

```
async function async1() {
  console.log("async1 start");
  await async2();
  console.log("async1 end");  // why will this task be placed in microtask?
}
async function async2() {
  console.log("async2");
}
async1();
console.log("script end");
```

I don't understand why will "console.log("async1 end")" be placed in microtask? in my opinion, the "console" should be a synchronized task rather than an asynchronous task.

Comment: `async`-`await` is syntactic sugar for `Promise(fn).then(res, rej)`, the code part after `await` is just the same as `res` callback passed to `then`.

Comment: "*in my opinion, the "console" should be a synchronized task rather than an asynchronous task.*" then it would run before the `async2` finishes. Which doesn't make any sense considering you've said `await` for it. Also, were it true, consider that `await` would be completely useless construct to keep code in line `let x = await p(); console.log(p)` would never log anything useful then.